# The top bar disapper half of it in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I just finished build my desktop today but after I installed the system I noticed the top part was missing half of it.(ps:I didn't install any indicated graphic card.) How can fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible this is a hardware issue? Many monitors have buttons on the monitor itself for changing the position.

For example, there's usually a "Menu" button of some sort, which brings up a display box which looks something like this:

[image]

Obviously the relevant option would be "vertical position", or your monitor's equivalent setting.